# Remove single item in play cache

Tags: scala, playframework

I am using a cache in my play scala (2.5) app. I want everything to remain cached except for the newRecipes - these I want to be fetched fresh each time. How do I remove a single item (newRecipes) from the cache?

```
package controllers

import javax.inject.{Inject, Singleton}

import models.Menu.MainMenus
import models.PrismicAPI.Prismic
import models.Products.{IndivProduct, NewProducts}
import models.Promotions.{RegularPromotions, ShortDatedPromotions}
import play.api.cache.Cached
import play.api.libs.concurrent.Execution.Implicits.defaultContext
import play.api.mvc.Controller

@Singleton
class FrontPage @Inject()(cached: Cached
                      , prismic: Prismic
                      , newProducts: NewProducts
                      , recipes: models.Recipes.Recipes
                      , mainMenu: MainMenus
                      , regularPromotions: RegularPromotions
                      , shortDatedPromotions: ShortDatedPromotions
                     ) extends Controller {

def landing(q: Option[String]) = cached("frontpage" + q) {

prismic.action() { implicit request =>
  for {
    topMenu <- mainMenu.futureMainMenu()
    footer <- models.FooterPDFs.futureFooterPDFs()
    carouselImages <- models.FrontPage.CarouselImage.futureCarouselImages()
    content <- models.FrontPage.FrontPageContent.futureFrontPageContent()
    taggedDocs <- models.FrontPage.FrontPage.frontPageTaggedDocs()
    newRecipes <- recipes.futureFrontPageRecipes(taggedDocs.filter(_.typ == "recipe"))
    newProducts <- newProducts.loadNewProducts(taggedDocs.filter(_.typ == "new-product"))
    recentNews <- models.News.NewsArticle.loadNewsArticles(taggedDocs.filter(_.typ == "news-article"))
    regularPromos <- regularPromotions.loadRegularPromos(taggedDocs.filter(_.typ == "regular-promotion"))
        shortPromos <- shortDatedPromotions.loadShortPromos(taggedDocs.filter(_.typ == "short-dated-promotion"))
      } yield {
....
```

Comment: cached.remove(newRecipes)

Answer (score 0):

see oficial docs for more help: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaCache#Accessing-the-Cache-API

```
val removeResult: Future[Done] = cache.remove("item.key")
```